# How to add an interval of seconds or microseconds to a teradata timestamp in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, teradata

I am working with sqlalchemy on a teradata database right now and am trying to get a select query to work, where I need to add both one full second and one hundred-thousandth of a second to a timestamp-column of a table.
However as of now all ways I found aren´t really working and dont properly translate into valid sql when compiled.
The sqlalchemy code I have right now after trying some different things while googleing is this:

```
 select_final = select([select_base])\
.where(and_(tuple_(*bks,t.columns.VALID_UNTIL + timedelta(seconds = 1))\
.notin_(select([select_not_in])),(tuple_(*bks,t.columns.VALID_UNTIL + timedelta(seconds = 0.000001))\
.notin_(select([select_not_in])))))
```

And this is the part of the "real" sql that we want to translate into valid sqlalchemy syntax:

```
and (a.VSNR,a.RISIKO_SCHL, a.GUELTIG_BIS_ZP + INTERVAL '1.000000' SECOND) is not in     (select b.VSNR,b.RISIKO_SCHL, b.GUELTIG_VON_ZP from P_LVM_CORE.AH_RISIKO as b where a.VSNR=b.VSNR and a.RISIKO_SCHL = b.RISIKO_SCHL      )
and (a.VSNR,a.RISIKO_SCHL, a.GUELTIG_BIS_ZP + INTERVAL '0.000001' SECOND) is not in     (select b.VSNR,b.RISIKO_SCHL, b.GUELTIG_VON_ZP from P_LVM_CORE.AH_RISIKO as b where a.VSNR=b.VSNR and a.RISIKO_SCHL = b.RISIKO_SCHL      )
```

What is the proper way to add an interval of time to a teradatasql-timestamp via sqlalchemy?

Thank you :)

Comment: Not sure there is a type mapping for INTERVAL SECOND types. You may need to generate the interval constant yourself, e.g. using text( )

Comment: related: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5672#issuecomment-719949679